# Change contents of "assign to"

Tags: trac

I activated restrict_owner to change the textfield to a dropdown when creating a new ticket. Is there a way to change the contents of that dropdown from user id's to user names?

The reason is, that all user id's that we use to log in are somewhat cryptic (something like xyz01, xyz02 and so on). If that list could show the associated user names, that you can enter in the prefs, that would be perfect.

Regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around that, I installed the [Auto-Complete Users Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AutocompleteUsersPlugin).  This will allow you to more easily select a user by account name, real name, or email address, plus it seems to have better performance than using `restrict_owner`.

I'm not sure if the plugin covers all of the same form fields as the `restrict_owner` option.  If there's one that it misses, it shouldn't be too difficult to modify the code and add another field.